# Trouble with table size

Tags: tables, width, height

I am having trouble with a table I am currently working on in latex. The width is fine and I know how to adjust the vertical spacing but the font size makes it impossible for anyone to read. Every time I get a code which fixes the reading problem. The width becomes a problem again. And when I fix the width, the vertical height becomes a problem. [image: Code and the result after compilation. I can adjust the [1ex] to be bigger but then that does not affect the text size]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the code itself, *not* a screenshot of the code. From what I can glean from the microscopic sceenshot font, I gather you're using `\resizebox`. One of the most common pieces of table-related advice given on this site is, NEVER USE RESIZEBOX. Your case could serve as Exhibit A for why this is excellent advice indeed. Please also indicate which document class you employ.

Comment: Do not use `resizebox` on a table in order to make it fit into the available space. Instead take a look at `tabularx`. Probalby `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cccX}` already solves your problem (Needs the `tabularx` package.)

Comment: Unrelated, but the `siunitx` package might be interesting for the units. For a less cramped look, remove the vertical lines and use the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package.

Comment: never use `resizebox` on tables (or you have the problem you describe) but if you want help with this specific table, post a small example as text in a code block not as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- First and foremost, get rid of the `\resizebox` wrapper.
- Place the table in landscape mode.
- Replace the `tabular` environment with its 4 `c` (centered, no linebreaks) columns with a `tabularx` environment, with line breaks permitted in all 4 columns.
- Make the fourth column about as wide as the first 3 columns taken together; see the code below for how you might achieve this.
- Don't overuse **bold-facing**: it's not needed in either the header row or the left-hand column.
- Give the table a more open look by getting rid of all vertical lines and by using fewer but well-spaced horizontal lines; make use of the `booktabs` package's macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\addlinespace`, and `\bottomrule`.
- Typeset quantities and scientific units using the `\SI` macro of the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page paramters suitably
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,siunitx,rotating}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X} % variable-width X-column

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable} % switch to landscape format
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{3}{L{0.66667}} L{2} @{}} % 3*0.667+2=4=# of X-columns
\toprule
Battery Type &
Largest Capacity (Commercial Unit) &
Location and Application &
Comments \\
\midrule
Leat Acid (Flooded Type) &
\SI{10}{\mega\watt}/\SI{40}{\mega\watt\hour} &
California --- Chino Load Leveling &
$\eta={}$72--78\%;
cost 50--150;
lifespan 1000--2000 cycles at 70\% depth of discharge;
operating temperature \SI{-5}{\degree} to \SI{40}{\degree};
\SI{25}{\watt\hour\per\kilogram};
self-discharge 2--5\%/month;
frequent maintenance to replace water lost during operation;
heavy
\\ \addlinespace % "\addlinespace" inserts vertical whitespace
Lead Acid (Valve Regulated) &
\SI{300}{\kilo\watt}/\SI{80}{\kilo\watt\hour} & 
Turn key system\slash load levelling &
$\eta={}$72--78\%;
cost \dots
\\ \addlinespace
Nickel Cadmium (NiCd) &
\SI{27}{\mega\watt}\slash \SI{6.75}{\mega\watt\hour} &
GVEA Alaska Contol Power Supply Var Compensation &
$\eta={}$72--78\%;
cost \dots
\\ \addlinespace
Sodium Sulphur (NaS) &
\SI{9.6}{\mega\watt}\slash\SI{64}{\mega\watt\hour} &
Tokyo Japan Load Levelling &
$\eta={}$79\% at \SI{325}{\degree};
lifespan \dots
\\ \addlinespace
Lithium Ion (Li-Ion) & & &
$\eta={}$100\%; 
cost 700--1000;
lifespan 3000 cycles at 80\% depth of discharge;
operating temperature \dots
\\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Battery technologies --- Characteristics and commercial units used in  \dots}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked! It was located between two paragraphs but I managed to fixed that. Thank you so much!